# Even Thickness in object

Tags: modeling

I am designing a implant and i want the thickness of it to be 1 mm evenly. I use the solidify modifier for that. 
But i noticed that when i am modelling it the thickness is not applied uniformly.  I have attached the photos. Can some one help ?

In flat surfce have 1 mm thickness.

When i change the angly the thickness decreased and then totally disappears in the last.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7349#7349

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you've applied the scale of your object (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in *Object* mode), and in the modifier enable the *Even Thickness* option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @moonboots

Comment: Also toggling ON High quality normals is a good idea usually.